# Objective-C thread safe code to prevent a crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, thread-safety, block

I got an iPhone crash report with a SIGSEGV and I think I've narrowed down the possible cause and a solution.
Since crashes caused by threads are hard to debug I can't repro this problem, but could use some help with my hypothesis - is it sound?

My code uses ASIHttpRequest to download a set of files using an ASINetWorkQueue. Here is a simplified sample

```
//initialize download queue and do this code block in a loop for each file

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:...
__block ASIHTTPRequest *fileRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:fileURL];

[fileRequest setCompletionBlock:^{
   //do some stuff   
}];
[fileRequest setFailedBlock:^{
    NSString *someError = [NSString stringWithFormat:...
    [self someErrorMethod:someError];       
}];

[downloadQueue addOperation:...
```

---

```
-(void)someErrorMethod(NSString *errorMessage) {
    DDLogWarn(errorMessage);

    if ([self downloadQueue]) {
        for (ASIHTTPRequest *request in [[self downloadQueue] operations]) {
            [request clearDelegatesAndCancel];
        }
        [[self downloadQueue] reset];
    }
 }
```

---

The top 2 lines of the crash report are

- libobjc.A.dylib 0x31846fbc objc_msgSend + 15
- MyApp 0x0002cab5 -[Myapp someErrorMethod:] (MyApp.m:)

---

My thinking for why this happened

- A file download fails and the failed block is called
- It goes through every request and clears delegates and cancels them and then resets the queue
- However, while it is till running, another file download fails and enters the failed block callback
- However, since it has now been cancelled, its failed block has been released
- When the code tries to log the error message, its memory has been released and unpredictable results follow

Does this make sense? Since I am newish to Objective-C, is my analysis correct or am I missing something obvious?

I am thinking of using a lock to make the errorMethod thread safe with the hope that it will fix this issue. Does that sound like the right solution based on the code above?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure about your error, but you may want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5023583/330494 You should use blocksafeSelf to reference self withing an ivar block.

Comment: Thanks Barlow

I am using a singleton class here that never gets deallocated so I dont think a retain cycle is a problem, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't sound likely. `ASIHttpRequest` likely performs all of its callbacks on the same thread (I'm fairly certain on this one).

If I had to guess, your error is more likely in this line:

```
DDLogWarn(errorMessage);
```

The first parameter to `DDLogWarn` is a format, not a string. This will likely crash in any case that `errorMessage` includes a %. What you meant is:

```
DDLogWarn(@"%@", errorMessage);
```

---

Since `DDLogWarn()` is a varags method, it will start substituting the (random) values it finds on the stack for any % substitutions in the string. It will read the stack until you run out of % substitutions. If any of the % substitutions are pointer-based (like %s or %@), then it will follow the pointer to a random location.

SEG_ACCERR means that you've requested a piece of memory you don't own. SEG_MAPERR means you've requested a piece of memory that is not mapped. Either is an expected result of following a totally random pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the response Rob.

That is indeed something foolish I missed. However, would that cause a SEGV_ACCERR?

I tried to repro with a % in the string and got a SEGV_MAPERR instead

    libobjc.A.dylib 0x0262509b objc_msgSend + 15
    CoreFoundation 0x0245f6f8 __CFStringAppendFormatCore
    CoreFoundation 0x023aab6c _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux 
    Foundation 0x0137f1a5 -[NSPlaceholderString    initWithFormat:locale:arguments:]
    Foundation 0x013cc66e -[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:]
    MyApp 0x00062867 +[DDLog log:level:flag:context:file:function:line:format:]

Comment: Updated; either form of SEGV would be expected.