# Objective-C / Blocks - Isn't this a retain cycle?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, retain-cycle

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) dispatch_queue_t dispatchQ;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *string;

@end

@implementation ClassA

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _dispatchQ = dispatch_queue_create("com.classa.q", NULL);
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)longRunningTaskWithCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    dispatch_async(self.dispatchQ, ^{

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            NSLog(@"%i", i);
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.string = @"Class A Rocks!";

            if(completion) {
                completion();
            }
        });
    });
}

@end
```

I'm thinking this code creates a retain cycle because the block in `-longRunningTaskWithCompletion:` captures self (to set the string property) in a block and adds the block to the dispatch queue property.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023566/objective-c-calling-self-methodname-from-inside-a-block

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a retain cycle, but it's temporary.  The retain cycle looks like this:

- `self` retains `dispatchQ`
- `dispatchQ` retains the block
- the block retains `self`

When the block returns, `dispatchQ` releases it.  At that point, the retain cycle is broken.  The block is deallocated and releases `self`.

Comment: After getting some sleep, drinking a cup of coffee, and retracing my steps, this is exactly how I processed this.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a retain cycle. To have a retain cycle, `self` would need to retain the block while the block retains `self`. In the posted code, `self` does not retain the block. Therefore there is no retain cycle.