# retain cycle when calling perfromBlock on self.managedObjectContext with ARC?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

In the code below, do I understand the retain cycle issue correctly and is there going to be a retain cycle?

```
- (NSError *)importRoute:(NSDictionary *)route {
    [self.importContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:self.importContext];
        //do I get a retain cycle here?
    }];
    ...
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)importContext {
    if (!_importContext) {
        id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _importContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        _importContext.parentContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    }
    return _importContext;
}
```

Comment: Presumably, `self` owns/maintains a strong reference to `_importContext`, `_importContext` probably copies the block passed into it and has a strong reference to it, and the block presumably retains `self`, so it definitely has the potential for a retain cycle.  I don't feel like I have a good handle on exactly when the retain cycles do happen and are a problem, but I do know that (1) clang sometimes warns me about them, and (2) it's easy enough to make a weak reference to self and use that inside the block, with no downside (at least, not in your use case and not that I've seen).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C / Blocks - Isn't this a retain cycle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515093/objective-c-blocks-isnt-this-a-retain-cycle)

Comment: you're right, self owns a strong reference to _importContext. The compiler does not warn about a retain cycle here and instruments do not show a cycle either. I just would like to clarify that in this case, there might actually not be a cycle although self is captured in the block...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a retain cycle, but it is temporary.  This is the retain cycle:

- `self` retains `importContext`
- `importContext` retains the block
- the block retains `self`

As soon as the block finishes executing, `importContext` releases it.  At that point the block's retain count becomes zero and it is deallocated.  When it is deallocated, it releases `self`.

Generally, a retain cycle involving a block is only an issue when the block is retained indefinitely, for example because you're storing it in a property, instance variable, or container.  If you're simply passing a block to a function that will execute the block once, in the near future, then you don't normally have to worry about a retain cycle.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I am beginning to understand how this is actually working. Much appreciated.